# Sharepoint Client OM: Create a document in a library from an existing document template

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently finding my feet with the Sharepoint 2010 client object model. I have a C#.net winforms application from which i need to access sharepoint.

I would like to programatically create a new document in a document library based on one of the document templates configured for that library. (Basically replicate the New Document drop down button functionality).

Desired functionality:

1. Show a form with the available content types. (i can do this, i load the list.ContentTypes for my library) Then i allow the user to select one of these content types.
2. Use the content type to create a document based on the Document Template that is configured for that content type. So there now exists a new document in the library with the content as sourced from the template doc.
3. Open the new document.

When i get to point 2 I'm stuck - I expect there to be some sort of Create New Doc From Content Type/Template functionality, but i can't find it.

Can anyone set me on the correct path to working this out?

Cheers!

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint has a specific pattern for creating and adding item to SPList - you can't create item which doesn't belong to list. Note that lists and document libraries are both instances of SPList in object model.

So you need to get reference on your SPList - use SPWeb.Lists collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.lists.aspx. TryGetList method is the best IMO.

After that call one of the Add method to create item in list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_methods.aspx.
You can change content type of newest created item by using this approach http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/c99b4599-0864-48bb-9977-2dd2066fbbb8. Call Update on item to apply content type.

Then set needed fields values for item.

Then call Update on item to save it to database.